Use globalShortCut to listen to key combination without overwriting system behaviour
Not much of a coder anymore nowadays and new to electron so hoping you can point me in the right direction.
Trying to replicate the deepl translation desktop interaction with Electron. When a user presses CTRL+C+C in an application (e.g. MS Word) Electron should popup and paste the clipboard contents in a textarea.
Taking it step by step I was trying to make it work with just a single CTRL+C via
globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+C', () => {
However this will prevent the default system behavior of copying the selection to the clipboard.
How can I make the Electron app respond to CTRL+C without overwriting the system behaviour?
Cheers

Used node-global-key-listener to listen to keyup events instead of hijacking globalShortcut.
